# Can mysqlimport utility create columns from source file if they do not exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysqlimport

I have a table with only an id column

```sql
CREATE TABLE daily_weather (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

I am using the **mysqlimport** utility to import data into this table.

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --local -u adminuser -plearnml fast daily_weather.csv
```

The CSV has around 20 columns, and it will be mighty tedious to create the column on the daily_weather manually.

Is there an option I can use on mysqlimport to create columns from the csv?

Comment: If you are creating a table for every day don't , create a table with a date and 20 columns and insert to it daily.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE` is a one-time task.  That involves picking column names, datatypes, NULLness, etc.  In the long run it is worth the effort to pick the datatypes carefully.  Once you have created the table, load new data into each day.

Assuming that the data source never changes the CSV format, no further action should be needed (other than the "import").